# How to link to a local SVG file in the Angular app?

Tags: angular, svg, icons, vmware-clarity

I'd like to replace a Clarity framwork icon with my own, using a local SVG file. I prepared a service for that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IconServiceService {

  icons: any = {
    'caret': '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><use xlink:href="file://help.svg#caret"></use></svg>',
  };

  constructor() { }

  public load() {
        window['ClarityIcons'].add(this.icons);
  }
}
```

It works when instead of the `<use xlink:href="file://help.svg#caret">` part I put the whole SVG content. However, when I want to link to a local file (like shown in the code) I cannot get the file. I'm using Angular 7. How can I use the local SVG file here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't load a file like SVG file directly. Assuming you are using the Angular CLI, then you can just piggy back on the `raw-loader` that is part of the Webpack build process like so below to import the raw string and assign it to your variable.

```
import * as CaretIcon from 'raw-loader!./path/to/file.svg';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IconServiceService {

  icons: any = {
    'caret': CaretIcon,
  };

  constructor() { }

  public load() {
        window['ClarityIcons'].add(this.icons);
  }
}
```

If you aren't using the CLI or Webpack, you can follow these instructions that would apply for SVG files the same way (just substitute the svg in for html). https://medium.com/@sampsonjoliver/importing-html-files-from-typescript-bd1c50909992

Comment: I'm using CLI but when I try yours solution I can't do the first import (Cannot find module 'raw-loader!./../../assets/icons/to/triangle.svg)

Comment: You might need to `npm install -D raw-loader` then, that is a webpack plugin to load raw files like this.

Comment: I tried to use it, as in the documentation: ```https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader```. Also, I tried svg-inline-loader. No possitive effect.

Comment: I use it like this (ng12): `import faUndo from "!!raw-loader!@cqg/icons/fontawesome/solid/undo.svg";`

Answer (score 2):

Solution worked for me

```js
let icons = require('!raw-loader!../../../styles/assets/icons/icons.svg');
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3879#issuecomment-358920021

you may need `declare const require: any;`